# Как убрать из ввода практически все точки с запятой?

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Моя программа считывает средний балл, а точка с запятой - разделитель, и если пользователь напишет вместо одной точки с запятой несколько, то программа должна убрать их и оставить только одну. Например:

```
Было: 5;;;4;;4;;;;
Стало: 5;4;4;
```

Я уже сделал примерно то же самое, но удаляя все пустые места в массиве, при этом не изменяя сам ввод. И да, насчёт точки с запятой в конце, про неё не надо писать. Моя программа её убирает

Comment: Можно регуляркой: `string output = Regex.Replace(input, ";+", ";");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если средний балл, то

```
string text = "5;;;4;;4;;;;";
string[] items = text.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
double avg = items.Select(double.Parse).Average();
Console.WriteLine($"Average = {avg:F1}");
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Average = 4.3
```

---

Если надо просто вывести через точку с запятой

```
string text = "5;;;4;;4;;;;";
string[] items = text.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = string.Join(";", items);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
5;4;4
```

Comment: Много чего узнал из вашего ответа. Спасибо